# Request to S3 from Lambda without leaving AWS Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have a lambda function accessing a S3 bucket using `aws-sdk`

There are a high number of operations(requests) to the S3 bucket, which is increasing considerably the cost to use lambda

I was hoping that the requests use the `s3://` protocol but there are going over the internet

I understand that one solution could be:

- Attach the Lambda to a VPC
- Create a VPC endpoint to S3
- Update the route tables of the VPC

Is there a simpler way to do so?

Comment: Yes, I think this would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be creating an API Gateway, and creating lambda proxy method integration following the AWS [Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html) or [Tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html).

You can then configure your apigateway to act as your external facing integration over the internet and your lambda / s3 stays within AWS.

Answer (score 0):

The traffic won't go over the internet and incur additional data transfer cost as long as the non-VPC lambda function is executing in the same *region* as the S3 bucket. So VPC is not needed in this case.

https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

> You pay for all bandwidth into and out of Amazon S3, except for the following:
>   • Data transferred in from the internet.
>   • Data transferred out to an **Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2)** instance, when the instance is in the same AWS Region as the S3 bucket.
>   • Data transferred out to Amazon CloudFront (CloudFront).

You can think of lambda as ec2. So the data transfer is free but be careful you still need to pay for api request.